# How are integrated SD-card readers connected?

Tags: laptop, usb, sd-card, memory-card, bus

Many laptop computers now feature integrated SD-card readers so that users can read/write SD-cards without needing to plug an external reader into a USB port.

Are these ***integrated*** SD-card readers typically connected via USB, or do they typically use a different type of bus?  How does one determine this for a Windows laptop?  If USB is being used, how does one determine if it is using USB3 versus an earlier version of USB?

Answer (score 4):

They are usually connected by an internal USB connection.
USB2 or USB3 is both possible. (USB2 seems still most common in my experience, but on newer laptops that are USB3 only I have seen USB3 variants.)
In some cases it is a PCI or PCIe device.

You can tell by opening the device manager.
Normally Windows shows "devices by type".
However in the menu you can switch it to show "devices by connection".
In that view simply look at the various PCI controllers and USB controllers/hubs and see on which one the card-reader shows up.

P.S. The Bluetooth adapter and web-cam are often connected to USB in the same way too. Picture below shows the Ricoh cardreader and the Bluetooth adapter on my own laptop.

[image: Showing both a card-reader on PCIe and a Bluetooth device at USB on my own laptop]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answer by "Tonny", if you have any recent laptop based on Intel SoC architecture (like Atom Z83xx of Braswell x5-E8000), the SD/MMC card reader can be integrated into the chip.
Example: http://www.cnx-software.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Intel_Atom_x5-E8300_Module_Block_Diagram.png

Comment: I have actually looked at a Braswell x5-e8000 system today and found that internally it used Usb3 for the reader.  The whole thing is integrated in the SoC but logically it is still a usb connection and it shows as such in the device manager.

Comment: You are correct. The x5-e8000 chip is a crippled version ($39) of  N3xxx Atom mobile processors ($100-130), where the SD/MMC ports are somehow removed. In full implementation [link](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/pentium-celeron-n-series-datasheet-vol-1.pdf), in "storage cluster", there are three direct SD/MMC interfaces. Therefore the SD/MMC ports on E8000 platform must be implemented via a different bus, likely as USB-SD bridge. In full-size chips all three SD/MMC interfaces should appear logically as internal PCI devices.

Comment: That is also the info I got from the hardware developers here. (We use these as embedded soc in some of our products.)